# How to fix property does not exist on type 'Element' error in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I get an error when I run a build. It says

> TS2339: Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Element'.

The code look likes:

```
const testCode = document.createElementNS('http://example.com/x/x', 'testtestCode');
testCode.body = widgetBody;
```

Tried to add 'as Element' or instanceof after the const, but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) has no body property, did you wanted to use `testCode.innerHTML` instead?

Comment: no I have custom properties, how to add that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more information in the comments, it's clear that you want to use custom properties on a custom element. You can do it like this:

```
interface MyCustomElement {
    body: string;
    model: string;
}

const testCode = document.createElementNS('http://example.com/x/x', 'testtestCode')
                 as Element & MyCustomElement;
testCode.body = widgetBody;
```

Casting the variable as Element & MyCustomElement will let you access the normal properties of the Element type while also being able to access your custom properties.

Comment: no, I need body and also model to use.
Which element type do I need to use both?

Comment: Well, what element type is it? This seems like a custom thing that you are specifying, and so it might need a custom type declaration.

Comment: yes correct, I have custom properties. I will search for adding custom type declarations. How can I do it like testCode.setAttribute('body', ..). ?